# SyntaxError in ContactsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

Hi Guys i m creating a application call 'app'. So far got a scaffolding 'contact' and just add a model call 'Address' (Address has street,city,region,zipcode,country 5 attributes), one contact could have one or several addresses. So here is my work.
 routes.rb

```
 App::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts
  resources :taggings
  resources :addresses
  root :to => 'Contacts#index'
end
```

model/contact.rb

```
    class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :Email, :Firstname, :Lastname, :Mobilephone, 
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :addresses, :through => :taggings
  validates_presence_of :Firstname, :Lastname
  attr_writer :address_street, :address_city, :address_region, :address_zipcode, :address_country
  after_save :assign_street, :assign_city, :assign_region, :assign_zipcode, :assign_country

  def address_streets
    @address_streets || addresses.map(&street).join('')
  end

  def address_citys
    @address_citys || addresses.map(&city).join('')
  end

  def address_regions
    @address_regions || addresses.map(&region).join('')
  end

  def address_zipcode
    @address_zipcodes || addresses.map(&zipcode).join('')
  end

  def address_countrys
    @address_countrys || addresses.map(&country).join('')
  end



  def assign_streets
    if @assign_streets
      self.addresses = @assign_streets.split(/\s+/).map do |street|
        Address.find_or_create_by_street(street)
      end
    end
  end

  def assign_citys
    if @assign_citys
      self.addresses = @assign_citys.split(/\s+/).map do |city|
        Address.find_or_create_by_city(city)
      end
    end
  end

  def assign_regions
    if @assign_regions
      self.addresses = @assign_regions.split(/\s+/).map do |region|
        Address.find_or_create_by_region(region)
      end
    end
  end

  def assign_zipcodes
    if @assign_zipcodes
      self.addresses = @assign_zipcodes.split(/\s+/).map do |zipcode|
        Address.find_or_create_by_zipcode(zipcode)
      end
    end
  end

  def assign_countrys
    if @assign_countrys
      self.addresses = @assign_countrys.split(/\s+/).map do |country|
        Address.find_or_create_by_country(country)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

model/tagging.rb

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :Address_id, :Contact_id
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :address
end
```

model/address.rb

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :City, :Country, :Region, :Street, :Zipcode
  has_many :tagging, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :contact, :through => :taggings
end
```

view/contact/_form.html.erb   **stop working since i add codes below!!:**

```
   <form>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :street %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address_street %>
    </p>
  </form>
```

And contact_controllor.rb  i haven't touched anything.  when i start my server and try to load into 'creating new contact'  rails tell me

```
SyntaxError in ContactsController#new

/media/sf_VM_working/app/app/models/contact.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
            ^
/media/sf_VM_working/app/app/models/contact.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
      self.addresses = @assign_streets.split(/\s+/).map do |street|
                                                          ^
/media/sf_VM_working/app/app/models/contact.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
      self.addresses = @assign_citys.split(/\s+/).map do |city|
                                                        ^
/media/sf_VM_working/app/app/models/contact.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

and

```
app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Could somebody help me checking where is the problem, i m not a good one :'(...thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra comma on line 2 of `contact.rb` - the first error message tells you this (as it discovers when it hits line 3):

> /media/sf_VM_working/app/app/models/contact.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>     has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy

And save yourself some grief by writing your attributes as *lowercase* (`:email, :firstname` instead of `:Email, :Firstname`)

Comment: thank you very much. when i create the model i used the upper case, so is that ok to use lowercase?

Comment: Databases are generally fine with this (case-insensitive) unless you modified the collation at some point.  In general, you'll have an easier time with Rails if you stick with the convention

Comment: Thanks a lot. now machine tell me... undefined local variable or method `street'

Comment: Try to troubleshoot the error on your own. Start a new question if you need further help with it.

Comment: In you contact/_form view - you have `f.label :street`.  It should probably be `f.label :address_street` similar to your `text_field`.

Comment: Machine gave me `app/models/contact.rb:10:in `address_street'
app/views/contacts/_form.html.erb:35:in `block in _app_views_contacts__form_html_erb___3814711525314209574_70075042839100'
app/views/contacts/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_contacts__form_html_erb___3814711525314209574_70075042839100'
app/views/contacts/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_contacts_new_html_erb___1951602963865205611_70075049767400'
app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:29:in `new'`